# Netflix won't load

Tags: netflix-desktop

I've recently had to switch to Ubuntu and am fumbling my way through. That being said, please help me be explaining each acronym.

I was directed to http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html this page in order to get everything for running Netflix on Ubuntu. I did download Wine, but when I went to the Dash Home and opened Netflix through there, nothing happens. Wine doesn't load to get the add-ons, Netflix doesn't load-nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix, much like Skygo uses Silverlight - which for ages now they have said is not supported (or actually works on linux).

There is away around this though for netflix - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-get-netflix-streaming-on-ubuntu-1210/

Answer (score 0):

There is also this link:-

http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_watch_Netflix_%28Watch_Instantly%29_in_Linux

It works like a dream on my Ubuntu 12.04